# Listagem de banco de dados SQL com NODEJS

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

Tenho o seguinte codigo

```html
  con.connect(function(err) {
       if (err) throw err;
  con.query("SELECT * FROM produtosinfos WHERE 1 ", function (err, result, fields) {
console.log(result)


var preco = result[0].Valor
var produt = result[0].Produto
var site = result[0].site

var imrimiresultado = "Site: "+site + "  Email: "+produt + "  Valor: "+preco

  bot.sendMessage(msg.from.id, imrimiresultado);
```

Porem ele imprimi apenas o 1 resultado do banco de dados , gostaria de imprimir os resultados de 10 em 10 , mas não estou conseguindo achar a logica , sou nova em NODEJS

Answer (score -2):

voce pode tentar usar o white

```html
  con.connect(function(err) {
       if (err) throw err;
  con.query("SELECT * FROM produtosinfos WHERE 1 ", function (err, result, fields) {
console.log(result)


var preco = result[0].Valor
var produt = result[0].Produto
var site = result[0].site

var imrimiresultado = "Site: "+site + "  Email: "+produt + "  Valor: "+preco

  bot.sendMessage(msg.from.id, imrimiresultado);
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).